# At least 1 capital, followed by numeric, optional dashes and space

Tags: java, regex

I want to implement regex which allows only capital, numeric, optional dash and space.

Format is: At least 1 capital, followed by numeric and optional dash and space.

I tried

```
/^[A-Z0-9- ]+$/
```

But it's not working. Can anyone please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add some sample data to your question, both positives and negatives?

Comment: `/^[A-Z0-9- ]+$/` <- This probably isn't working the way you expect because you put the hyphen in between two other characters within the character set, which causes it to specify a range (instead of matching literal hyphen). Try `/^[A-Z0-9 -]+$/`

Comment: Use `\-` to represent a literal hyphen.

Comment: Try it like this `^[A-Z]+[0-9]+[ -]*$` to match 1+ char A-Z followed by 1+ digits and optional spaces and dashes. Or `^[A-Z0-9- ]*[A-Z][0-9][A-Z0-9- ]*$` To match at least an uppercase A-Z followed by a digit.

Comment: @JavaSSE If you're not satisfied yet, please provide some samples the should match and some other that should fail. Emma's and especially the 4t bird's idea look good, don't they.

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned "Atleast 1 capital followed by numeric and optional dash and space"

this is the regular expression for at least one Capital letter at first followed by any number of letters, hypens and spaces

```
^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 -]*$
```

In case you meant Capital letter at any position,

this is the regular expression for at least one Capital letter at any position , and only containing zero or more letters[upper and lowercase] , numbers, space and hyphen at other positions

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 -]*[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 -]*$
```

> This is valid
>
> This is valid 2
>
> This is n*t valid
>
> thiS is valid 3
>
> this Is -4 valid
>
> This + is not VALID.
>
> --- this is Valid 2 --